# Unable to tap on image in an ipad app

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I have this image in an app. I want to simulate a tap on the image. The image is located as follows:

`target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().images()["patch blue right.png"].images()[4].`

My javascript code is as follows:

`target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().images()["patch blue right.png"].images()[4].tap();`

But after running the code, the following error message is shown:

`Error: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().images()["patch blue right.png"].images()[4] could not be tapped .`

I have checked that the image is Valid . But the image is not visible. 
Can anyone tell me if I can not tap on element that is valid but not visible?.

Comment: While recording, line is scipted:  target.tap({x:176.00, y:168.00});   But on playback that image is not tapped. If the image is not visible as per IsVisible(), then  what coordinates are being recorded,Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: An element may be valid, but hidden [element setHidden:TRUE] and not eligible to receive taps. UIUatomation is not able to tap just like an actual user would not be able to.

Comment: Actually manually i can tap on the image ,i.e. I  can see the image, but while playback /automation that image is not captured..

Comment: In that case, perhaps the problem is your code above. Are you sure that "target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().images()["patch blue right.png"].images()[4]." is correct? It seems odd to have images() twice in there. A good way to get the correct element is to use the record button in your script and tap the image.

Comment: okay, I even tried that, so then it got recorded as  target.tap({x:176.00, y:168.00}); that is coordinates are being recorded. But on playback it does not tap on the desired image.

Comment: Well, are you sure that the code with two "images()" in it that you posted above is correct? You can see the correct code in the script after tapping the element while recording.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, you cannot tap on an element that is not visible.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590353/tap-command-on-a-button-not-working-in-uiautomation)